# Stack around the variable ' ' was corrupted in c++

Tags: c++

I m getting a run-time error when I try to call a constructor , and I think I m not doing right the memory deletion. Here is my construcor :

```
const int id_ferma;
int suprafata;
int nr_produse;
char* produse[];

Ferma(int id_ferma, int suprafata, int nr_produse, char* produse[]) :id_ferma(id_ferma){
        this->suprafata = suprafata;
        this->nr_produse = nr_produse;
        for (int i = 0; i < nr_produse; i++){
            this->produse[i] = new char[strlen(produse[i]) + 1];
            strcpy(this->produse[i], produse[i]);
            cout << produse[i] << endl;
        }
    }
```

And here is my destructor:

```
~Ferma(){
    for (int i = 0; i < nr_produse; i++){
            if (this->produse[i] != NULL)
                delete produse[i];
    }
}
```

And main:

```
int main(){
        char* produse1[] = { "Lapte oaie", "Branza vaca", "Muschi de porc", "Oua de gaina" };
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            cout << produse1[i];
        }
        Ferma f1(14, 1500, 4, produse1);
    }
```

Comment: stop manual memory management once and for all.

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating any memory for `this->produse` before trying to populate it.  Also, because you are manually managing dynamically allocated memory, you need to implement the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)) manually as well.

Try this instead:

```
#include <algorithm>

class Ferma
{
private:
    int m_id_ferma;
    int m_suprafata
    int m_nr_produse;
    char** m_produse; // <-- change this to char**!

public:
    Ferma(int id_ferma, int suprafata, int nr_produse, char* produse[])
        : m_id_ferma(id_ferma), m_suprafata(suprafata), m_nr_produse(nr_produse)
    {
        m_produse = new char*[nr_produse]; // <-- add this!

        for (int i = 0; i < nr_produse; ++i)
        {
            m_produse[i] = new char[strlen(produse[i]) + 1];
            strcpy(m_produse[i], produse[i]);
        }
    }

    Ferma(const Ferma &src) // <-- add this!
        : m_id_ferma(src.m_id_ferma), m_suprafata(src.m_suprafata), m_nr_produse(src.m_nr_produse)
    {
        m_produse = new char*[m_nr_produse];

        for (int i = 0; i < m_nr_produse; ++i)
        {
            m_produse[i] = new char[strlen(src.m_produse[i]) + 1];
            strcpy(m_produse[i], src.m_produse[i]);
        }
    }

    ~Ferma()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < m_nr_produse; ++i)
            delete[] m_produse[i]; // <-- change this to delete[]!

        delete[] m_produse; // <-- add this!
    }

    Ferma& operator=(const Ferma &rhs) // <-- add this!
    {
        Ferma tmp(rhs);
        std::swap(m_id_ferma, tmp.m_id_ferma);
        std::swap(m_suprafata, tmp.m_suprafata);
        std::swap(m_nr_produse, tmp.m_nr_produse);
        std::swap(m_produse, tmp.m_produse);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

That being said, you should stop using manual memory management.  Use `std::vector` and `std::string` instead, let the STL handle all of the memory management for you:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class Ferma
{
private:
    int m_id_ferma;
    int m_suprafata;
    std::vector<std::string> m_produse;

public:
    Ferma(int id_ferma, int suprafata, int nr_produse, char* produse[])
        : id_ferma(id_ferma), m_suprafata(suprafata)
    {
        m_produse.reserve(nr_produse);

        for (int i = 0; i < nr_produse; ++i)
            m_produse.push_back(produse[i]);

        // alternatively:
        // std::copy(produse, produse+nr_produse, std::back_inserter(m_produse));
    }

    // no destructor, copy constructor, or copy assignment operator needed!
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not initialising the `produse` field.

If you want to use C++ idiomatically you should use `vector` instead of raw arrays and `string` instead of `char*`.

Comment: please tell me , how should I do it , I am a noob in c++

Answer (score 0):

Since you allocate memory with `new[]`, you need to deallocate it with `delete[]`:

```
int *p = new int[10];
...
delete[] p;

int* p[1] = {new int[10]};
...
delete[] p[0];
```

And since `produse` is `char **`, you should allocate memory for `produse` before trying to dereference it:

```
char **produse = new char *[10];
produse[0] = new char [10];
...
delete[] produse[0];
delete[] produse;
```